# How do I add a line break to a string that is output by PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace

There is a heading output in my ad statistics page (WordPress):

```
<h3 id="ad-title"><?php printf( __( 'Statistics for %s', 'advanced-ads-tracking' ), $ad_name ); ?></h3>
```

I want to add a line break after the “Statistics for” part.

The Find and Replace plugin (filters HTML after generated by WP and before it’s sent to the browser) is not able to replace the string, I am not sure why – my ad stats page is generated within the WordPress context so it should work, but it doesn’t.

There is no filter hook in ad-stats.php, there is only an action hook.
But I cannot use an action hook to replace a string, I would need a filter hook.

I want to use str_replace to replace the string, adding the line break in it.

How do I do that?

Or can I add a filter hook?

Comment: You want a newline or a something html interprets as a newline?  With html, maybe try:  `'Statistics for<br>%s'`  For a newline:  `"Statistics for\n%s"`  Note the use of double quotes for interpolation, single for a string constant.

Comment: Thanks. But the concern is, how do I make this change without an existing filter hook?

Comment: Let me help you out.  You need to specify the actual plugins you are using ;) Adding it as a tag will also help people who might have some experience find your question.

Comment: The plugin bundle is WP Advanced Ads.
The Tracking plugin. There is no tag available for this plugin. I thought there is a generic method included in WP or PHP that can be used, indifferently of the plugin code.

Comment: I suspect you might have better luck with your question on the [wordpress specific stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In php you can do it

- by adding '\n' to the string at the break point
- by using *PHP_EOL* Constant
- by adding '<br>' the break row tag in html

Comment: Right. But the concern is, how do I make the change without a filter hook, and if HTML filtering with the plugin doesn't work?